# How to calculate the remainder of the days

Tags: java

I am making a small program to calculate for me how many years and days are in a specific amount of minutes. It is giving me the amount of years nicely but not the days this number (1556640) for example.

'''

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type");
        int totalMin = n.nextInt();
        int year;
        int totalYears = totalMin / 518400;
        int remaining  = totalYears % 518400;
        int totalDays = remaining / 1440;
        System.out.println(totalYears + " years and " + totalDays + " days");

    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

The remaining minutes after taking off the complete years should probably be:

```
int remaining  = totalMin - totalYears * 518400;
```

Example:

```
int totalMin = 600000;
int totalYears = totalMin / 518400;
int remaining  = totalMin - totalYears * 518400;
int totalDays = remaining / 1440;
System.out.println(totalYears + " years and " + totalDays + " days");
```

prints

> 1 years and 56 days

Comment: no it doesn't, unless `totalMin` is a multiple of 518400.

Comment: aah ok this way! but isn't (%) this sign made to solve this thing for you?
so why isn't it working?

Comment: You could indeed use `int remaining = totalMin % 518400` instead.

Comment: and that didn't work using my code. which is my problem.

Comment: My example is based on your code, except for the input which is hardcoded. Don't you agree with the output?